# How to not duplicate rows in PHP / MySQL when importing files

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script to upload my CSV file to a MySQL everyday I get an update. But let's say I am importing and my colleague thought I didn't do it and imported it again. But I want MySQl to skip the rows that he imported since the data are already there. I tried `IGNORE` and `REPLACE` but I am not getting the result I want.

```
if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) {

    $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name];
    $handle = fopen($file,"r");

    do {
        if ($data[0]) {
            mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO cdl_genesys_login (EMP_ID, NAME, MANAGER, TYPE, START_TIME, END_TIME, TIMEZONE, DURATION, STATE, REASON_KEY, DATE) VALUES
                (
                    '".addslashes($data[0])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[1])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[2])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[3])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[4])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[5])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[6])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[7])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[8])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[9])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[10])."'
                )
            ") OR die (mysql_error());
        }
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","\""));

    header('Location: import_.php?success=1'); die;

}
```

Comment: Why does everybody don't look at the documentation? why there's so much new code using mysql_* functions?

Comment: Add primary/unique keys to your table.

Comment: for insert ignore to work, it nees to encounter an error, and by adding PK, you encounter the error of adding dublicate and ignore it

Comment: while are you doing a `do { ... } while(...);` if you don't have `$data` at the first iteration?